# RegExp, How can i concat a string in javascript to create a dynamic regular expression?

Tags: javascript, regex, expression

How can i concat a string in javascript to create a dynamic regular expression?
The commented line works fine.

```
var numericValidator = function (value, callback)
{
    var decimalSymbol = ServerVar.NumberDecimalSeparator == "." ? "\." : ",";

    console.log(decimalSymbol);

    var regExNum = new RegExp("^-?(?:\d+|\d{1,3}(?:[\s\]\d{3})+)(?:[" + decimalSymbol + "]\d+)?");
    if (regExNum.test(value)) {
    //if (/^-?(?:\d+|\d{1,3}(?:[\s]\d{3})+)(?:[\.,]\d+)?$/.test(value)) {
        if (callback) callback(true);
        return true;
    }

    if (callback) callback(false);
    return false;
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use two escape chars

```
var regExNum = new RegExp("^-?(?:\\d+|\\d{1,3}(?:[\\s\\]\\d{3})+)(?:[" + decimalSymbol + "]\\d+)?");
```

Comment: ahh, thanks I guess I have to double escape the decimalSymbol too?

Comment: @Josh yes you do.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using ES6 strings which are very appropiated for such cases.

```
var numericValidator = function (value, callback)
{
    var decimalSymbol = ServerVar.NumberDecimalSeparator == "." ? "\." : ",";

    console.log(decimalSymbol);
    var regExNum = new RegExp(`^-?(?:\d+|\d{1,3}(?:[\s\]\d{3})+)(?:[${decimalSymbol}]\d+)?`);        
    if (regExNum.test(value)) {
    //if (/^-?(?:\d+|\d{1,3}(?:[\s]\d{3})+)(?:[\.,]\d+)?$/.test(value)) {
        if (callback) callback(true);
        return true;
    }

    if (callback) callback(false);
    return false;
};
```

Such strings are delimited by backticks (`).

Notice the use of `${<exp>}` to embed scope expressions within your string.